# Monitoring Kafka Consumer Lag

Tags: monitoring, apache-kafka

I want to write a shell script to monitor consumer lag in my cluster using

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --zkconnect localhost:2181 group test
```

mentioned at http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_consumer_lag.
I have 3 servers that are being used as zookeeper's do I need provide the address to all 3 as a parameter to get a report for a consumer groups running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, no. Zookeepers will communicate among themselves and then respond with an answer that is in agreement with all of the servers. This is one of the assumptions that Zookeeper runs on, unless they are experiencing failures.

If you query one, if it has enough information, it will respond, and, if not, it will ask the other zookeepers for the information and then reply.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in general you should because if you specify a minority of servers in your zkconnect and that minority is not available your call will fail even if the zookeeper ensemble is up and running.

Comment: Whenever we run zookeeper connect, even establishing connection with single zookeeper will provide required information. We need to specify specific servers only when we are running broker related services. After 0.8x a lot of services are being migrated to Kafka instead of zookeeper.

Comment: What happens when the zookeeper mentioned in the zookeeper connect is not available and you restart your service ? 
It wont' come up, it is necessary to have at least one of the servers mentioned in zookeeper connect to be up and running, on starts and restarts.